# Center All Content In Each Div - Responsive?

Tags: html, css

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

#center {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="left">
            Test Test Text
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="center">
            Image
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="right">
            Text Image
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I have read so many posts but still cannot make this work. I am missing something. I want to have these three divs in my header. The center div should be centered in the middle of the page and it will be a image. The other divs will be on the left and right and a combination of text and images as desired. I want all 3 divs to have their content vertically and horizontally centered. How do I do this and maintain some responsiveness for users on div browser and screen sizes. Responsiveness is secondary issue, getting the content aligned is the main challange. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: table` for row and `display: table-cell` for columns

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    display: table;
}

.col {
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left {
    background-color: red;
}

#center {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: green;
}

#right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col" id="left">
      Test Test Text
    </div>
 <div class="col" id="center">
  Image
 </div>
 <div class="col" id="right">
  Text Image
 </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: I think this is the approach I will use. Thanks it seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS3 flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for it:

```css
.row, .col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.col {
    height: 200px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

#left {
    background-color: red;
}

#center {
    background-color: green;
}

#right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="left">
            Test Test Text
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="center">
            Image
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="right">
            Text Image
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/4u8ebs2c/1/)

Comment: @BasicBlue it is supported by all modern browsers, check it on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), the state in the specification — [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).